# Google-Apps-Script For loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm learning GoogleAppsScript trying to create some simple code.
In this example I want my code to check in the 3rd column if employees are male or female then return "Man" or "Woman" in the 4th column.
The problem is that the For loop seems not to work correcly and returns "Man" for each employee

Here is my code :

```
function employees() {

// set variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var employees = ss.getSheetByName("Employees");
  var lastRowEmployees = employees.getLastRow();

// loop on each employee
  for (var i=2;i<lastRowEmployees+1;i++) {
    var employeeNumber = employees.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var employeeName = employees.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var employeeSex = employees.getRange(i,3);

    if (employeeSex.getValue = "M") {
      employeeSex.offset(0,1).setValue("Man");}
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: One of the most common mistakes: `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

This tweaked script below will fix your for loop issue:

### Script

```
function employees() {
  // set variables
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var employees = ss.getSheetByName("Employees");
    var lastRowEmployees = employees.getLastRow();

  // loop on each employee
  for(var row=2; row <= lastRowEmployees; row++){
    var employeeNumber = employees.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    var employeeName = employees.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    var employeeSex =  employees.getRange(row,3);

    if(employeeSex.getValue() == "M"){
      employeeSex.offset(0,1).setValue("Man");
    }else{
      employeeSex.offset(0,1).setValue("Female");
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Test

> ***Test Sheet***

[image]

> ***After running the script***

[image]